# How to add a new entry to a multiple has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship, has-many

I am not sure am I doing these correct.

I have 3 models, Account, User, and Event.

Account contains a group of Users. Each User have its own username and password for login, but they can access the same Account data under the same Account.

Events is create by a User, which other Users in the same Account can also read or edit it.

I created the following migrations and models.

---

**User migration**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.integer     :account_id
      t.string      :username
      t.string      :password
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

---

**Account migration**

```
class CreateAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :accounts do |t|
      t.string      :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :accounts
  end
end
```

---

**Event migration**

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.integer     :account_id
      t.integer     :user_id
      t.string      :name
      t.string      :location
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :events
  end
end
```

---

**Account model**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many      :users
  has_many      :events
end
```

---

**User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to    :account
end
```

---

**Event model**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to    :account
  belongs_to    :user
end
```

---

so....

1. Is this setting correct?
2. Every time when a user create a new account, the system will ask for the user information, e.g. username and password. How can I add them into correct tables?
3. How can I add a new event?

I am sorry for such a long question. I am not very understand the rails way in handling such data structure. Thank you guys for answering me. :)

Comment: Are you sure you want to create username and password automatically? isn't this up to the user via a form?

Comment: users are required to type in their own username and password during the account registration proces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job for [has_many :through](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001833) (scroll down to find the `:through` option)

If you need to know the user that created the event, then you should specify that Event really belongs only to a user:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to    :user
end
```

Accounts, however, can "grab" their user's events. You specify that like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :events, :through => :users
end
```

The migrations would be the same as you wrote for `Account` and `User`. For `Event` you can remove the `account_id`:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.integer     :user_id
      t.string      :name
      t.string      :location
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :events
  end
end
```

Then your events can be created like this:

```
# These two are equivalent:
event = user.events.create(:name => 'foo', :location => 'bar')
event = Event.create(:user_id => user.id, :name => 'foo', :location => 'bar')
```

Notice that this will create and save the event inmediately. If you want to create the event without saving it, you can use `user.events.build` or `Event.new` instead.

The `has_many :through` on Accounts will allow you to get all the events for one account:

```
user.events         # returns the events created by one user
account.events      # returns all the events created by the users of one account
user.account.events # returns the events for the user's account
```

As a final note, please note that you are reinventing the wheel a lot here. There are pretty good solutions out there for managing users and permissions.

I recommend you to have a look at [devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) ([railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise)) or [authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) ([railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic)) for managing your accounts, and [declarative_authorization](http://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization)([railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization)) or [cancan](http://github.com/ryanb/cancan)([railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan)) for managing permissions. My personal choices are devise and declarative_authorization. The former is easier to install than authlogic, and the later is more powerful than cancan.

Regards, and good luck!

Comment: thanks buddy. i look for these gems for long. will take a deep look in devise and declarative_authorization.